# How to assign member function to a member variable, defined using std::function?

Tags: c++

This is my stripped-down program, where I'm trying to use *function variables* to modify class functionality at run time. So - I declare a member variable `m_func` using the `std::function` template and a function `myFunc` with compatible signature:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
  T():m_func([](int){return true;}) {}
  void assign() {m_func = &T::myFunc;}    // <======== Problem is here
  void call(int M) const {std::cout << m_func(M) << std::endl;}
private:
  bool myFunc(int N) {return (N >= 4);}
  using func = std::function<bool(int)>;
  func m_func;
};

int main()
{
  T t;
  t.assign();
  t.call(6);
}
```

However, the compiler (g++ 4.8.4 with -std=c++11 option) gives me an error with long output, saying that `template argument deduction/substitution failed` and a lot more...

Why can't I assign the `myFunc` function to the `m_func` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void assign() {m_func = &T::myFunc;}
```

Member function pointers have an implicit `this` pointer that needs to be passed as the first argument in their signature. Either use `std::bind` to bind that first,

```
void assign() {
    m_func = std::bind(&T::myFunc, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

or use a lambda-expression (capturing `this`).

```
void assign() {
    m_func = [this](int arg){ return this->myFunc(arg); };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A non-static member function pointer cannot be assigned to `std::function` directly. The general solution for this problem is to bundle the `this` pointer into a lambda like this :

```
void assign() { 
    m_func = [this](int N) { 
        return this->myFunc(N); 
    };
}
```

In your case, it seems simpler to just make `myFunc` static.

```
struct T
{
    T() :m_func([](int) {return true; }) {}
    void assign() { m_func = &T::myFunc; }
    void call(int M) const { std::cout << m_func(M) << std::endl; }
private:
    static bool myFunc(int N) { return (N >= 4); }
//  ^^^^^^ static methods can be assigned to std::function directly
    using func = std::function<bool(int)>;
    func m_func;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't make the `myFunc` static, cause in reality it needs to access a bunch of member variables

Answer (score 4):

If you want the member function to be called on the current object, then you want:

```
m_func = std::bind(&T::myFunc, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: I think you're missing a placeholder.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I did indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Kerrek SB above, you could use `std::bind`.

However, it's better to use a lambda since it can have less overhead :

```
m_func = [this] (int N) {return myFunc(N);};
```

Comment: As for the overhead - do you mean overhead during this assignment, or the overhead during the `m_func` call? (I care about the second case actually)

Comment: Actually I'd say both of them.